# Target (variable "") is not a signal error in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have this piece of code

```
  function func (k1, k2 : in bit_vector) return bit_vector is

    variable result : bit_vector(1 to 32);

    begin
        for i in 0 to 31 loop
            result(i) <= k1(i);
        end loop;

        return result;
    end func;
```

I get this error :

> target (variable "result") is not a signal

I know I need to change the type of result but I don't know what it should be.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When assigning to a variable use `:=` as:

```
result(i) := k1(i);
```

Assign with `<=` is for assign to signal.

The range of `result` (`1 to 32`) does not match the range in the loop (`0 to 31`), so first assign in the loop (`result(0) := k1(0)`) will cause in a range error.  Fix this by changing either `result` or loop range.